# Is that possible to overwrite ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, proxy, httprequest, head

My web application now remove to proxy and all `Request.UserHostAddress` (same thing to `ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]`) return proxy IP adress.

I know I could replace `Request.UserHostAddress` with `ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]`, but it's tedious.

I just wonder if I could overwrite `ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` to real client IP in proxy
 
So, that no code need change?